# Aliasing of otherwise equivalent signed and unsigned types

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer

The C and C++ standards both allow signed and unsigned variants of the same integer type to alias each other.  For example, `unsigned int*` and `int*` may alias.  But that's not the whole story because they clearly have a different range of representable values.  I have the following assumptions:

- If an `unsigned int` is read through an `int*`, the value must be within the range of `int` or an integer overflow occurs and the behaviour is undefined.  Is this correct?
- If an `int` is read through an `unsigned int*`, negative values wrap around as if they were casted to `unsigned int`.  Is this correct?
- If the value is within the range of both `int` and `unsigned int`, accessing it through a pointer of either type is fully defined and gives the same value.  Is this correct?

Additionally, what about compatible but not equivalent integer types?

- On systems where `int` and `long` have the same range, alignment, etc., can `int*` and `long*` alias?  (I assume not.)
- Can `char16_t*` and `uint_least16_t*` alias?  I suspect this differs between C and C++.  In C, `char16_t` is a typedef for `uint_least16_t` (correct?).  In C++, `char16_t` is its own primitive type, which compatible with `uint_least16_t`.  Unlike C, C++ seems to have no exception allowing compatible but distinct types to alias.

Comment: What do you mean by "X read through Y" ?

Comment: `X x = <value>;  Y* yp = (Y*)&x; Y y = *yp;` for example.

Comment: Annex J.3.5 (implementation-defined behaviour), C11 draft standard: `— The result of, or the signal raised by, converting an integer to a signed integer type
when the value cannot be represented in an object of that type (6.3.1.3).` I invite you to check out Section 6.3.1.3. It answers your question.

Comment: @EOF Thanks!  Didn't realise conversions were treated differently than arithmetic overflow.

Comment: The C and C++ standards are written to accommodate some very weird CPU architectures, so there are seemingly sensible guarantees that don't get made. However, 99.9% of us are never going to encounter a weird architecture. You can generally rely on a compiler to simply reinterpret the bit pattern based on the type. Anything else would be such a surprising result that it wouldn't be likely to last in the real world.

Comment: Glad you badgered a correct answer to be deleted for your ignorance then, @TavianBarnes.

Comment: @MarkRansom Fully understood, I'm just curious about exactly what the standard is trying to allow with the exception for aliasing signed and unsigned types.  Hence the [language-lawyer] tag.

Comment: @EOF I didn't downvote the answer, I would have loved to see it corrected.  It also didn't say the behaviour was implementation defined, it said that `(int)UINT_MAX` is `-1` which is still not guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: @TavianBarnes But reading `X` through `Y` is _not_ a conversion.

Comment: @TavianBarnes I think the main motivation is to allow the programmer to do things similar to what happen when evaluating varargs, where passing `int` where `unsigned` is expected and vice versa is legal, _as long as the value fits in both types_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *If an `int` is read through an `unsigned int*`, negative values wrap around as if they were casted to `unsigned int`. Is this correct?*

For a system using two's complement, type-punning and signed-to-unsigned conversion are equivalent, for example:

```
int n = ...;
unsigned u1 = (unsigned)n;
unsigned u2 = *(unsigned *)&n;
```

Here, both `u1` and `u2` have the same value. This is by far the most common setup (e.g. Gcc documents this behaviour for all its targets). However, the C standard also addresses machines using ones' complement or sign-magnitude to represent signed integers. In such an implementation (assuming no padding bits and no trap representations), the result of a conversion of an integer value and type-punning can yield different results. As an example, assume sign-magnitude and `n` being initialized to -1:

```
int n = -1;                     /* 10000000 00000001 assuming 16-bit integers*/
unsigned u1 = (unsigned)n;      /* 11111111 11111111
        effectively 2's complement, UINT_MAX */
unsigned u2 = *(unsigned *)&n;  /* 10000000 00000001
        only reinterpreted, the value is now INT_MAX + 2u */
```

Conversion to an unsigned type means adding/subtracting one more than the maximum value of that type until the value is in range. Dereferencing a converted pointer simply reinterprets the bit pattern. In other words, the conversion in the initialization of `u1` is a no-op on 2's complement machines, but requires some calculations on other machines.

> *If an `unsigned int` is read through an `int*`, the value must be within the range of `int` or an integer overflow occurs and the behaviour is undefined. Is this correct?*

Not exactly. The *bit pattern* must represent a valid value in the new type, it doesn't matter if the old *value* is representable. From C11 (n1570) [omitted footnotes]:

> **6.2.6.2 Integer types**
>
> For unsigned integer types other than unsigned char, the bits of the object representation shall be divided into two groups: value bits and padding bits (there need not be any of the latter). If there are **N** value bits, each bit shall represent a different power of **2** between **1** and **2<sup>N-1</sup>**, so that objects of that type shall be capable of representing values from **0** to **2<sup>N</sup>-1** using a pure binary representation; this shall be known as the value representation. The values of any padding bits are unspecified.
>
> For signed integer types, the bits of the object representation shall be divided into three groups: value bits, padding bits, and the sign bit. There need not be any padding bits; `signed char` shall not have any padding bits. There shall be exactly one sign bit. Each bit that is a value bit shall have the same value as the same bit in the object representation of the corresponding unsigned type (if there are **M** value bits in the signed type and **N** in the unsigned type, then **M≤N**). If the sign bit is zero, it shall not affect the resulting value. If the sign bit is one, the value shall be modified in one of the following ways:
>
> - the corresponding value with sign bit 0 is negated (sign and magnitude);
> - the sign bit has the value **-2<sup>M</sup>** (two's complement);
> - the sign bit has the value **-2<sup>M</sup>-1** (ones' complement).
>
> Which of these applies is implementation-defined, as is whether the value with sign bit 1 and all value bits zero (for the first two), or with sign bit and all value bits 1 (for ones' complement), is a trap representation or a normal value. In the case of sign and magnitude and ones' complement, if this representation is a normal value it is called a *negative zero*.

E.g., an `unsigned int` could have value bits, where the corresponding signed type (`int`) has a padding bit, something like `unsigned u = ...; int n = *(int *)&u;` may result in a trap representation on such a system (reading of which is undefined behaviour), but not the other way round.

> *If the value is within the range of both `int` and `unsigned int`, accessing it through a pointer of either type is fully defined and gives the same value. Is this correct?*

I *think*, the standard would allow for one of the types to have a padding bit, which is always ignored (thus, two different bit patterns can represent the same value and that bit may be set on initialization) but be an always-trap-if-set bit for the other type. This leeway, however, is limited at least by ibid. p5:

> The values of any padding bits are unspecified. A valid (non-trap) object representation of a signed integer type where the sign bit is zero is a valid object representation of the corresponding unsigned type, and shall represent the same value. For any integer type, the object representation where all the bits are zero shall be a representation of the value zero in that type.

---

> *On systems where `int` and `long` have the same range, alignment, etc., can `int*` and `long*` alias? (I assume not.)*

Sure they can, if you don't use them ;) But no, the following is invalid on such platforms:

```
int n = 42;
long l = *(long *)&n; // UB
```

> *Can `char16_t*` and `uint_least16_t*` alias? I suspect this differs between C and C++. In C, `char16_t` is a typedef for `uint_least16_t` (correct?). In C++, `char16_t` is its own primitive type, which compatible with uint_least16_t. Unlike C, C++ seems to have no exception allowing compatible but distinct types to alias.*

I'm not sure about C++, but at least for C, `char16_t` is a typedef, but not necessarily for `uint_least16_t`, it could very well be a typedef of some implementation-specific `__char16_t`, some type incompatible with `uint_least16_t` (or any other type).

Answer (score 4):

> If an `unsigned int` is read through an `int*`, the value must be
>   within the range of `int` or an integer overflow occurs and the
>   behaviour is undefined. Is this correct?

Why would it be undefined? there is no integer overflow since no conversion or computation is done. We take an object representation of an `unsigned int` object and see it through an `int`. In what way the value of the `unsigned int` object transposes to the value of an `int` is completely implementation defined.

> If an `int` is read through an `unsigned int*`, negative values wrap
>   around as if they were casted to unsigned int. Is this correct?

Depends on the representation. With two's complement and equivalent padding, yes. Not with signed magnitude though - a cast from `int` to `unsigned` is always defined through a congruence:

> If the destination type is `unsigned`, the resulting value is the
>   least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo
>   *2<sup>n</sup>* where `n` is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [ Note: In a two’s complement representation, this
>   conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if
>   there is no truncation). — end note ]

And now consider

```
10000000 00000001  // -1 in signed magnitude for 16-bit int
```

This would certainly be *2<sup>15</sup>+1* if interpreted as an `unsigned`. A cast would yield *2<sup>16</sup>-1* though.

> If the value is within the range of both int and unsigned int,
>   accessing it through a pointer of either type is fully defined and
>   gives the same value. Is this correct?

Again, with two's complement and equivalent padding, yes. With signed magnitude we might have `-0`.

> On systems where `int` and `long` have the same range, alignment,
>   etc., can `int*` and `long*` alias? (I assume not.)

No. They are independent types.

> Can `char16_t*` and `uint_least16_t*` alias?

Technically not, but that seems to be an unneccessary restriction of the standard.

> Types `char16_t` and `char32_t` denote distinct types with the same
>   size, signedness, and alignment as `uint_least16_t` and
>   `uint_least32_t`, respectively, in `<cstdint>`, called the underlying
>   types.

So it should be practically possible without any risks (since there shouldn't be any padding).

Comment: "Why would it be undefined?"  I thought `(int)UINT_MAX` was undefined if `UINT_MAX > INT_MAX`.  Turns out it's merely implementation-defined.

Comment: @TavianBarnes Yes, see [conv.integral]/3.

Comment: The standards seem to guarantee that the `intN_t` types use 2's-compliment representation.  So provided they exist, `uint32_t *` and `int32_t *` may alias, right?  But otherwise, it seems mostly everything is up to the implementation.

Comment: @TavianBarnes: Yes, they can alias, they are corresponding signed and unsigned types. Since C11, redefining typedefs is allowed (if compatible, of course), so I think you could do some static assertion via `typedef unsigned uint32_t;` or the like. If that compiles, even `int` and `uint32_t` can alias.

Comment: I don't think the restriction of the standard is unnecessary. There are likely optimization opportunities (and some time some compiler might choose to use them) and it's not really a restriction for the programmer (just declare your variables how you want to use them). Especially for `(u)int8_t` this may be useful, because, unlike `char`, this cannot alias everything (which is horrible for an optimizing compiler).

Comment: @mafso Sorry by "may alias" in that comment, I really meant the stronger condition of "may alias, and dereferencing either gives the same value provided it is within the range of both types."

Comment: @TavianBarnes: Then it's easy. The `intN_t` types behave quite peaceful. No padding bits or other wierd stuff and 2's complement. The result is always defined (and portably predictable, provided the types exist), and if the value is representable in both, type-punning is value-preserving (that's the case for all types if there is no UB, but this is not always guaranteed).

Comment: "Why would it be undefined?"  Because the standard doesn't define any behavior in this case, and when the standard doesn't define any behavior, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @TavianBarnes Concerning the "implementation-defined", the C standard clearly says that the "implementation-defined" value could be a signal.  Not that it's relevant to the OPs question, because the OPs question doesn't involve any conversions.

Comment: Concerning `int32_t` and `uint32_t`: a conforming implementation on a 32 bit system could define them as `int` and `unsigned long`, respectively.  (I can't imagine it actually happening, but it _is_ legal.)  In that case, `int32_t*` and `uint32_t*` may not alias.

Comment: @JamesKanze What exactly is the aspect not covered by [conv.lval]? No indeterminate values are involved.

Comment: @Columbo How does |conv.lval| have anything to do with the question?

Comment: @JamesKanze Very much. An lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is the aspect that defines access of a stored value of any scalar, and a vital part of most discussions about aliasing. I refer to N3797.

Comment: @Columbo |conv.lval| concerns converting a glvalue of type `T` to
a prvalue (also of type `T`).  In particular, "If the object to which
the glvalue refers is not an object of type T and is not an object of
a type derived from T, or if the object is uninitialized, a program that
necessitates this conversion has undefined behavior."  In our case, the
glvalue has type `unsigned int`, and the lvalue has type `int`.  Unless
there is something else which contradicts this, the results are
undefined behavior, even for common values.

Comment: @JamesKanze I mentioned above that I refer to N3797. There is a very clear reason that this phrase was removed for C++14 (which is the latest official standard)

Answer (score 1):

It is not defined that happens since the c standard does not exactly define how singed integers should be stored. so you can not rely on the internal representation. Also there does no overflow occur. if you just typecast a pointer nothing other happens then another interpretation of the binary data in the following calculations.

Edit
Oh, i misread the phrase "but not equivalent integer types", but i keep the paragraph for your interest:

Your second question has much more trouble in it. Many machines can only read from correctly aligned addresses there the data has to lie on multiples of the types width. If you read a int32 from a non-by-4-divisable address (because you casted a 2-byte int pointer) your CPU may crash.

You should not rely on the sizes of types.  If you chose another compiler or platform your `long` and `int` may not match anymore.

**Conclusion:**
Do not do this. You wrote highly platform dependent (compiler, target machine, architecture) code that hides its errors behind casts that suppress any warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your questions regarding `unsigned int*` and `int*`: if the
value in the actual type doesn't fit in the type you're reading, the
behavior is undefined, simply because the standard neglects to define
any behavior in this case, and any time the standard fails to define
behavior, the behavior is undefined.  In practice, you'll almost always
obtain a value (no signals or anything), but the value *will* vary
depending on the machine: a machine with signed magnitude or 1's
complement, for example, will result in different values (both ways)
from the usual 2's complement.

For the rest, `int` and `long` are different types, regardless of their
representations, and `int*` and `long*` cannot alias.  Similarly, as you
say, in C++, `char16_t` is a distinct type in C++, but a typedef in
C (so the rules concerning aliasing are different).